observeAsState or collectAsState in Kotlin MultiPlatform application
What I should use for live refresh data on my KMM application with Firestore DB?
Use ObserveAsState with:
userViewModel.userInfo.observeAsState(null).apply {
    // view or edit document here
}

with userInfo LiveData:
val userInfo: LiveData<UserInfo?> = liveData {
        try {
            emitSource(repo.getUserProfile().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main))
        }catch (_: Exception) { }
    }

or to call directly userInfo from repository with collectAsState:
serViewModel.repo.getUserProfile().collectAsState(null).apply {
   // view or edit document here
}

the getUserProfile() in repo looks like this:
fun getUserProfile(): Flow<UserInfo?> = flow {
    firestore.collection("UserInfo").document(auth.currentUser!!.uid).snapshots.collect { user ->
                emit(user.data<UserInfo>())
            }
    }

Both versions work, I just don't know which is the best and fastest for live data sync on mobile. Any improvements are welcome.

LiveData is only needed when using the old view system in Android with XML layouts.
The modern approach is to use Flows. When you use Compose for the UI you use collectAsState (or collectAsStateWithLifecycle when you want it to be lifecycle-aware) to convert them into Compose State.

what I should use in the view model then? Should I call the repo directly? without View Model?

In a typical layered app Compose only accesses the view model, the view model accesses the repositories and the repositories access data sources. Compose and view models are part of the UI layer, repositories and data sources are part of the data layer. All of that is just a convention, though. It is possible - but not recommended - to directly access the data sources from Compose.

how should the function look like in view model if I use collectAsState?

The view model just transforms the repository flow into ui state (the data class used to represent the current state of your ui) by calling mapLatest and the likes and then exposes it as a StateFlow by calling .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000), /*initial value*/) on the transformed flow. -- Btw., you can also use mapLatest on the snapshots flow in the repository instead of collecting and re-emitting it.

I did not understand what you want to say. Could you show me an example please?

Comments are not a place for extended discussions. Please ask a new question if you have additional questions. This question is just about the comparison of observeAsState and collectAsState.

could you edit your comment and add the correct code please?

Comments are not for extended discussions and cannot be edited. If you want to know more about how to transform and convert flows, please ask a new question. If the above answer answered your question about the comparison of observeAsState and collectAsState you can accept it by ticking the check mark next to it.

I created a new ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79242578/best-way-to-use-collectasstate-in-an-kmm-app-with-viewmodel-arhitecture
Thanks for the help so far!


Both versions work

In this case, you should continue to work with the one you are more comfortable with. However, in modern Android development, it's more recommended to use Kotlin Flows, especially when you're building an app using KMM.
Please also note that the LiveData is not tied in any way with Android views. LiveData is a data holder class that can be observed within a given lifecycle, no matter if you're using views or composable functions to create the layouts.

Hey Cipri. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
